# PHP: How to display a value from the first part of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I can't figure this out...

How do I display a value from the first part of an array like this:

```
$payments['plan'][] = array(
    'hours'   => '2 Hours', 
    'price_a' => '90.00',
    'price_b' => '190.00',
);
$payments['plan'][] = array(
    'hours'   => '3 Hours', 
    'price_a' => '110.00',
    'price_b' => '220.00',
);
$payments['plan'][] = array(
    'hours'   => '4 Hours', 
    'price_a' => '120.00',
    'price_b' => '350.00',
);
```

In the above, let's say I wanted to display -- "90.00" -- how would I get that from the array?

I've tried different variations of reset, done some searching, can't figure this out... just how to display that value from the first part of the array.

Any suggestions?

---

Doing this:

```
reset($payments);
echo key($payments['plan']);
```

I just get the result: "0"

Comment: `echo $payments['plan'][0]['price_a'];` - [Take note of example #4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thanks for sending the link, this one thing always fly's right over my head! It's mind boggling to me lol, I feel like foreach loops handle it differently because I never have to add the 0 in those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key of the first 'block' is `0`, so:

```
echo $payments['plan'][0]['price_a']
```

Comment: My god, I don't know why I always miss that when I'm working with arrays! That damn 0 value always gets me lol, thanks... feels like such a waste asking on here when it's something that just fly's over my head

Answer (score 2):

just use `echo $payments['plan'][0]['price_a'];`

Inside a loop, you could use :

```
foreach($payments['plan'] as $index => $values) {
    echo $values['price_a'];
}
```